# Cannot figure out Kata Direction Reduction problem error

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a direction reduction problem from codewars and I can't figure out the error it is giving me. I know there have been similar cases as this but when I test my code on Visual Studio Code it works flawlessly so I'm not sure why codewars is giving me this error. The error I am getting is: "NORTH","SOUTH","SOUTH","EAST","WEST","NORTH": array lengths differed, expected.length=0 actual.length=6

Here is my code. Keep in mind that codewars tests it for you so my main method is not actually needed:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class DirReduction {

public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {
    int directionNS = 0;
    int directionEW = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == "NORTH"){
            directionNS++;
        } else if(arr[i] == "SOUTH"){
            directionNS--;
        } else if(arr[i] == "EAST"){
            directionEW++;
        } else if(arr[i] == "WEST"){
            directionEW--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Direction.");
        }
    }


    String[] reducArray;
    if(directionNS == 0 && directionEW == 0){
        reducArray = new String[arr.length];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, reducArray, 0, arr.length);

    } else {
        reducArray = new String[Math.abs(directionNS + directionEW)];
        if(directionNS > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < directionNS; i++){
                reducArray[i] = "NORTH";
            }
        } else if(directionNS < 0){
            for(int i = 0; i > directionNS; i--){
                reducArray[i] = "SOUTH";
            }
        } 


        if(directionEW > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < directionEW; i++){
                reducArray[i] = "EAST";
            }
        } else if(directionEW < 0){
            for(int i = 0; i > directionEW; i--){
                reducArray[i] = "WEST";
            }
        } 
    }
    return reducArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] a = {"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH","WEST"};

    String[] result = dirReduc(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were four errors I found.

1) The case "NORTH","SOUTH","SOUTH","EAST","WEST","NORTH" should end up back where you started, so the array length should be 0, as requested by Codewars. To get that to work, I got rid of your special case for both direction counts being 0 and let what had been your else case deal with it by adding 0 and 0 to get the array size. [This error is the one mentioned in your question]

2) Your calculation of the array size was a little off. For example for "SOUTH" "EAST" it was calculating a size of 0 because they canceled out. Instead you need to sum the absolute values, not take the absolute value of the sum.

3) Your EAST/WEST in the reduced array were starting at position 0, and so overwriting NORTH/SOUTH. I made sure to offset into the array before doing those.

4) Your strategy of going negative on the for loop will try to write to a negative index if you have like SOUTH, EAST, SOUTH. I kept it positive using Math.abs

Here is the resulting method.

```
public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {
    int directionNS = 0;
    int directionEW = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == "NORTH") {
            directionNS++;
        } else if (arr[i] == "SOUTH") {
            directionNS--;
        } else if (arr[i] == "EAST") {
            directionEW++;
        } else if (arr[i] == "WEST") {
            directionEW--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Direction.");
        }
    }


    String[] reducArray;
    //removed special case for ending up back where one started, that will be made a 0 length array as it should be
    reducArray = new String[Math.abs(directionNS) + Math.abs(directionEW)]; //note have to take abs of each so one does not cancel out the other
    if (directionNS > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < directionNS; i++) {
            reducArray[i] = "NORTH";
        }
    } else if (directionNS < 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.abs(directionNS); i++){//keep the i's positive so they work in the array easily
            reducArray[i] = "SOUTH";
        }
    }


    if (directionEW > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < directionEW; i++) {
            reducArray[i + Math.abs(directionNS)] = "EAST"; //note have to start where north south left off
        }
    } else if (directionEW < 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.abs(directionEW); i++){
            reducArray[i + Math.abs(directionNS)] = "WEST";
        }
    }

    return reducArray;
}`
```

Comment: You're amazing! It ran perfectly for me on Visual Studio Code and passed all of Codewars sample tests. It failed the actual attempt but for a reason I am unsure of. It only listed the answer as "EAST" but even following the directions logically the answer should be "NORTH", "EAST". Thanks again!

Comment: what was the test it failed?

Comment: "EAST", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST", "EAST", "EAST", "SOUTH", "NORTH", "WEST": arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<[EAST]> but was:<[NORTH]>

Comment: Do they want it alphabetized? So EAST NORTH, but you give NORTH EAST?

Comment: It doesn't specify that so thats why I'm confused. The only other thing I could think of is that the directions have to stay in the same order. So since it said EAST before it said NORTH then it has to stay that way. But once again, the problem does not specify this..

Comment: There must be some order it has in mind so that it can check solutions against something unique. I guess you will fiddle with it and see. Good luck.